# Android Mapbox geocoding

Tags: android, geocoding, mapbox

I was trying to convert an address string into geo location.
Here is the simple code:

```
MapboxGeocoder client = new MapboxGeocoder.Builder()
.setAccessToken(MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN)
.setLocation("some place")
.setProximity(longitude, latitude)/*a location of new zealand*/
.setType(GeocoderCriteria.TYPE_ADDRESS)
.build();
```

It works fine and return a list of location from all over the world, however, I only want it return the location in New Zealand. How can I setup a boundary.

Comment: why can't you check the country name from Geocoder ?

Comment: @Rahul It seems only return top 5 results by default (no idea how does it get picked), and I couldn't see a place to setup the return count either. And it does happen that the 5 results are all out of new Zealand.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [country](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-java/blob/master/mapbox/libjava-services-rx/src/main/java/com/mapbox/services/api/rx/geocoding/v5/GeocodingServiceRx.java#L20-L37) parameter to limit results to a particular country. You can also use the bbox param to limit results to an arbitrary bounding box. The proximity parameter is just a bias, not a strict filter.

More information is available from the [API docs](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#geocoding).

Answer (score 0):

To get "setCountry" you need to us MapboxGeocoding not MapboxGeocoder like this

```
import com.mapbox.services.api.geocoding.v5.*;
```

.

```
 MapboxGeocoding client = new MapboxGeocoding.Builder()
            .setAccessToken("pk.eyJ1IjoiamViMTkyMDA0IiwiYSI6ImNpbWNyODZyaDAwMmZ1MWx2dHdzcHQ5M2EifQ.IZsMnB3wOYFIaX1A5sy7Mw")
            .setLocation(constraint.toString())
            .setCountry("us")
            .setGeocodingType(GeocodingCriteria.TYPE_POI)

            .setProximity(position)

            .build();
```

I wasn't able to get setCountry until I used this.

Comment: can you please tell me library name which we define in gradle file .. lilke implimentation...